# How to ask user for input for mysql

Tags: mysql, bash

I have the following problem that if I can resolve I will have fully automated all sections of required input.
I have correctly injected sql statements into mysql via bash script, but this relies on an _EOT and the correct password already included in the script. If the password is different than that then you have to go to the line in the script and enter the correct password you require then run the script.
This is counter-intuitive to wanting full automation of the script. So, here is the section where I inject the sql statements:

```
echo "This section of the script will configure mysql users and databases as per requirements:"
password=$(grep "temporary password" /var/log/mysqld.log | awk '{print $NF}') << "_EOT"
echo "DEBUG: The temporary password from the log is: $password"
output=$(mysql --connect-expired-password -uroot -p"$password")
ALTER USER `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY '<password>',`root`@`localhost` PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
SET GLOBAL validate_password_policy=LOW;
ALTER USER `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY '<password1>',`root`@`localhost` PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;
quit
_EOT
```

Is there a way where I can ask the user to supply the password into a variable and then inject the variable into mysql in place of having to type into the bash-script the passwords?

Answer (score 0):

In Bash you can use `read` for user inputs.
Example:

```sh
echo "Enter User Name:"
read user_name
echo "Enter the password:"
read -sp user_pw
echo "The current User is $user_name"
echo "The password is $user_pw"
```

You can also use `read -s` for the password input to be "silent" or `read -p` to input on a new command prompt.

Comment: Thanks Sikorsky. I know how to complete the read option for the user input. What I am asking is, can I do that in the middle of this script and then utilise the variable in the sql commands within the script that state "Password" and "Password1"?

Comment: As far as I know you can declare the variable in the middle with `local`.

Comment: The read command did not work because, as expected, the script believes at this point that it should be an sql statement. My original question stands is how I can inject the entered password into mysql? I can read the input, which sits outside of the EOT expected sql statements but I cannot seem to be able to inject that into the code for mysql. Maybe scripting cannot do that... I have tried outside and inside and neither works.